# Custom Property name for FromUrl Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a model which is used to bind QueryString, that follows the naming conversation of c# but the QueryString is in a different naming conversation. How to provide a custom property name for model properties that are assigned vis `FromUrl`?

```cs
// Will NOT work
public class FormatDatabaseRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("_type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Name = "awef_flag")]
    public string AwefFlag { get; set; }
}

// Controller.cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> FormatDatabaseAsync([FromUri] FormatDatabaseRequest request) {}

// Sample URL (QueryString MUST be named _type and awef_flag)
// https://localhost:43521/myControllerName?_type=asdfa&awef_flag=asdf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fields from URL like that, I recommend using `[FromQuery]` attribute, like so:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromQuery] FormatDatabaseRequest data)
```

Then, such URL

```
https://localhost:43521/myControllerName?type=asdfa&awefflag=asdf
```

Will be parsed correctly to your object :)

Comment: I need `myControllerName?_type=asdfa&awef_flag=asdf` as my URL

Comment: Also, FromQuery is part of AspNetCore, I need to for AspNet

Answer (score 0):

json has nothing to do with query string. I don't understand why you don't like underscore properties, but you can hide them like this

```
public class FormatBaseRequest
{
    public string _Type { get; set; }
    public string Awef_flag{ get; set; }
} 
public class FormatDatabaseRequest:FormatBaseRequest
{
   
    public string Type 
    { 
        get { return _Type; }
       set { _Type=value ; } //or leave just get
    }

   
    public string AwefFlag 
   { 
       get { return Awef_flag; }
       set { Awef_flag=value ; } //or leave just get
    }
}
```

you can use it for query string and for c#